# How to get the full name from LDAP using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get the full name of a user after login from LDAP using PHP. I connected successfully to LDAP but getting the full name based on username is still not working.

Here is my code

```
 <?php 
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
$account_suffix = '@*****.com';
$hostname = '**.**.*.***';


$ldap = ldap_connect($hostname);
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap,$username . $account_suffix, $password)) {
  echo "success";
  if ($bind) {
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=****,dc=com",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
        {
            if($info['count'] > 1)
                break;
            echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($info);
            echo '</pre>';
            $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
        }
        @ldap_close($ldap);
    }
} else {
  echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Any suggestions please what am i missing ? Thank you.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.  Add a bunch of debug prints or var_dump in your code.  Check one by one each line.  Ex. $result, $info, $info["count"], $userDn, ...  You do use a `var_dump($info)`, that does not help?  It could help us to see what you get.  It could just be `$info[$i]["sn"][0]` that is not referenced properly, we need to see our var_dump to know.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the connection to Active Directory you need to set a couple of options to ensure a functioning link, like this:

```
...
$ldap = ldap_connect($hostname);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap,$username . $account_suffix, $password)) {
...
```

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper Any response to this answer? Did it solve your problem?